# Output json data from database Laravel into separate input fields

Tags: arrays, json, database, laravel, laravel-5

So I have multiple inputs saving into one column in json format into the database, and on retrieving I am turning that json into an array to output the correct data.

```
<input type="text" name="waypoints" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" value="{{ json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true)[0] }}">
```

The above code is the 1st item in the array showing in an input, so if I where to list

```
{{ json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true)[0] }}
{{ json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true)[1] }}
{{ json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true)[2] }}
```

It would output the array correctly. But, how do I work out how many is in the array and only show the correct number of input fields? (max number is 10)

I tried using `@foreach ($myroutes as $myroute)` and `@endforeach` around the input field but I received an error message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like so:

```
@foreach(json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true) as $v)

  <input type="text" name="waypoints[]" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" value="{{ $v }}">

@endforeach
```

However it would be easier if you can respond with an array rather that a json response.

like so:

`return view('edit')->with('myroutes', json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true))`;

and in your view:

```
@foreach ($myroutes as $v) 

    <input type="text" name="waypoints[]" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" value="{{ $v }}">

@endforeach
```

Comment: Are you sure your data is a type of json?

Comment: Just noticed it works when there is more than one input, but its showing that error if there is only one waypoint. Should note the waypoint can also be null.

Comment: Quick solution: `@foreach(json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true) ?? [] as $v)`

Comment: @devk Thanks!. Yes that would be a great solution.